# Django admin delete icon for foreign key

Tags: django, django-admin

In my django admin I've got some foreign keys, I can always add and edit those fields, but sometimes I can also delete them.

On attached picture it is shown that `Kategorie hotelu` and `Wojewodztwo` have this little red cross, where `Galeria zdjec` and `Miasto` does not have it.

Why is that ? How can I add this little red cross to my `Galeria zdjec` ?

[image: Django admin panel]

Also here is requested admin

```
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from hotels.models import HotelCategory, Hotel, DescriptionInlines
from django.utils import timezone
from django_select2.forms import Select2Widget
from django import forms
from image_cropping.widgets import ImageCropWidget


class StackedinlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DescriptionInlines
        fields = '__all__'


class HotelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Hotel
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'city': Select2Widget,
            'gallery': Select2Widget,
            'main_image': ImageCropWidget,
            'logotype': ImageCropWidget
        }

    def clean(self):
        premium_status = self.data.get('premium_status', None)
        display_on_main_page = self.data.get('display_on_main_page', None)

        if display_on_main_page and not premium_status:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                (mark_safe(u"Nie można wyświetlać hotelu na stronie głównej, który nie jest hotelem premium."))
            )


class DescriptionInlinesAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    form = StackedinlineForm
    model = DescriptionInlines
    extra = 1

    suit_classes = 'suit-tab suit-tab-cities'


pnt = Point(20.00, 52.00, srid=4326)
pnt.transform(3857)


class HotelAdmin(admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
    form = HotelAdminForm
    default_zoom = 6
    default_lon, default_lat = pnt.coords
    list_display = ['name', 'city', 'street_and_number', 'tv_status', 'wifi_status', 'spa_status',
                    'beach_status', 'breakfast_status', 'pool_status', 'premium_status', 'is_active',
                    'display_on_main_page',
                    ]
    list_filter = ['city', 'stars', 'tv_status', 'wifi_status', 'spa_status', 'beach_status', 'breakfast_status',
                   'pool_status', 'premium_status', 'display_on_main_page',
                   ]
    search_fields = ['name']
    readonly_fields = ['visits', 'visits_unique']

    inlines = (DescriptionInlinesAdmin, )

    filter_horizontal = ['tags', ]
    exclude = ('slug', )

    suit_form_tabs = (
        ('general', u'Dane podstawowe'), ('cities', u'Dodatkowe opisy'), ('main_page', u'Obróbka zdjęć'),
    )

    fieldsets = [
        (None, {
            'classes': ('suit-tab', 'suit-tab-general',),
            'fields': ['name', 'old_slug', 'display_on_main_page', 'main_image', 'logotype', 'stars', 'gallery', 'video',
                       'categories', 'voivodeship', 'city', 'postcode', 'street_and_number', 'phone', 'email',
                       'webpage', 'description', 'price_starting_at', 'booking_com_url', 'tv_status', 'wifi_status',
                       'spa_status', 'beach_status', 'breakfast_status', 'pool_status', 'premium_status',
                       'premium_end_date', 'distance_to_city', 'facebook_url', 'twitter_url', 'ok_url', 'vk_url',
                       'location', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'tags', 'visits_unique', ]
        }),
        (None, {
            'classes': ('suit-tab', 'suit-tab-main_page',),
            'fields': ['col4', ]
        }),
    ]

    def is_active(self, obj):
        if not obj.premium_status:
            return None
        else:
            if obj.premium_end_date:
                if obj.premium_end_date >= timezone.now():
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                return False

    is_active.short_description = u'Aktywny hotel premium'
    is_active.boolean = True

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('/statics/css/select2.min.css',)
        }
        js = ('/statics/js/hotel_admin_select2.js',)


admin.site.register(HotelCategory)
admin.site.register(Hotel, HotelAdmin)
```

Comment: can you post your AdminModel class ?

Comment: could you please tell me what Galeria zdjec and Miasto field is named in model and the same as Wojewodztwo. Also please check your models for on_delete attribute? What are the on_delete attribute are for each?

Comment: thank you on_delete=models.SET_NULL worked

Answer (score 0):

`on_delete=models.SET_NULL`

Worked